# C - return variable always blank if max length is greater than 50

Tags: c, return-value, fgets

I'm really stumped on this one.

I have written a simple program in c to retrieve first name, last name and YOB (year of birth) from the user keyboard input (i haven't got around to parsing age into an integer yet) and I set a maximum number of characters for the input.

But whenever I allow the max characters for a field to be 50 or greater, the return value is always blank.

This is the code (60 lines), output to follow. The function causing trouble is the second to last function, getInputNoNewLine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void flushBuffer();
char *getInput(int max, char message[]);
char *getInputNoNewline(int max, char message[]);

typedef struct Person {
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int yob;
} Person;

void flushBuffer() {
    int ch; 
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); //flush the input buffer
}

char *getInput(int max, char message[]) {
    char in[max];
    char *input;
    do {
        printf("%s", message);
        input = fgets(in, max + 2, stdin); //max + 2 accounts for characters fgets adds
        if (input[strlen(input)-1] != '\n') {
            printf("Sorry, maximum %d characters\n", (max));
            flushBuffer();
        }
    } while (input[(strlen(input)-1)] != '\n');
    printf("input: %s", input); //debug
    return input;
}

//OFFENDING FUNCTION
char *getInputNoNewline(int max, char message[]) {
    char *input;
    input = getInput(max, message);
    printf("raw input : %s", input); //debug
    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n') { //strip new line character
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("final input: '%s'\n", input); //debug
    return input;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numPlayers = 3;
    char *intIn;
    int i = 0;
    Person players[numPlayers]; 
    printf("Hello world Game\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        players[i].firstName = getInputNoNewline(50, "What is your first name: "); //50 will return blank
        players[i].lastName = getInputNoNewline(49, "What is your last name: "); //49 will return fine
        intIn = getInputNoNewline(4, "What is your YOB: "); //TODO: convert number to integer with sscanf
        printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    }
    printf("Finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output, as you can see the first input of jim is received from fgets, but the return value is blank (raw input : ). If I was to reduce the max value from 50 to 49, as per the case for the last name field, it works perfectly fine. Any thoughts?

```
Hello world Game
What is your first name: jim
input: jim
raw input : final input: ''
What is your last name: smith
input: smith
raw input : smith
final input: 'smith'
What is your YOB: 1984
input: 1984
raw input : 1984
final input: '1984'
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you allocate `in` to be 50 character long, and you allow 52 characters to be read, you will run into trouble! You want to use

```
static char* in;
if(in!=NULL) free(in);
in = (char*)malloc(max + 2);
```

This addresses both the point that Alok raised (about local scope pointer not being defined once function returns), and the fact that your function allows `fgets` to write `max+2` characters into the buffer `in`.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified or changed lines where appropriate and it works now. 2 questions, 1) max+2 doesn't seem like a great method for dealing with the terminator and newline characters fgets add, is there a better way? if i leave the lines to read **in = (char*)malloc(max)** and **input = fgets(in,max,stdin)** then where i'm trying to allow 4 characters as a maximum length, it will actually only allow 2 characters... 2) I'm still curious as why it only returned a blank value when max = 50 or greater, if max = 49 or less it returned the proper value. would you know why?

Comment: Adding some "protection" is never a bad idea - if you need a string with 15 characters, you have to assign 16 to account for the \0 character as well... If you expect \r\n at the end of your string, you really need three characters `\r\n\0` of space... Depending on how blocks of data are allocated, I can imagine they are aligned on four byte boundaries - so the 50 bytes might "sit" on a 52 byte boundary... in which case if you needed three additional spaces you got lucky with 49, but not with 50. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has an **Undefined behavior**.
You are returning a pointer to a locally allocated array.

```
char *getInput(int max, char message[])
{
    char in[max];
    ....
    ....
    return input;
}
```

`in` is a array local the function and is guaranteed to be alive only till the function scope ``` {``} ```. To be able to access the contents of this array beyond the scope of function you need to increase the lifetime of the array by:

- Allocating it dynamically using `malloc` or
- Making it `static` or global

If you use `malloc` do not forget to deallocate the array after use by calling `free` or you end up with a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of memory management issues going on.  The fgets call is begging for a crash since you're passing in a length 2 bytes greater than the allocated memory.  You are also returning the char * returned from fgets and treating it like it's allocated memory.

You should copy the buffer returned from fgets and store it in your Person struct.

Really, I think you should review basic C memory allocation and destruction.